# Daemon accessible via TCP to keep SSH sessions open, create new sessions and send commands

Tags: php, c, ssh, openssh

I am currently designing some SSH control software to send commands to groups of servers. The front-end is written in PHP and I am currently using the Net_SSH2 PHP extension. This proves to be problematic when I attempt to execute multiple commands at once, or request the output of a command over SSH from a server with more than 150ms latency (takes several seconds to receive output)
Is there existing software that would allow me to create SSH sessions, keep them open (reconnect if disconnected) and send commands to the session of my choosing without opening a new connection each time I would like to send a command?
I am currently working with this setup
- Centos 6.3 64bit
- Nginx with PHP-FPM

Any ideas would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a remote PHP listener that uses `exec()` and receives by `POST`. Then you don't need to use SSH at all.

Invoker:

```
//command to execute is sent to this page
//prepare data
//use cURL to POST to listener
```

Listener:

```
//request is received
//process request
exec($command);
```

Comment: +1 for the Minecraft control panel. But that's not what I'm developing. :) I need to use SSH as the communication method though, so your method would not be suitable, sorry.

Comment: It /would/ work but I require SSH communication as it is very secure and does not require extra software (PHP or a web server) to be installed on the receiving end.

Comment: How does `ssh2_shell` or `ssh2_tunnel` look?

Comment: Would a connection initiated via either of those functions be able to remain connected after the script has finished executing and then accessed via another script?

Comment: A shell establishes a live connection so yes, and you could probably put the session into a screen session. Then when another script comes in, they could resume the screen.